# Div blocks clicks

Tags: css, web

I have a div that blocks clicks in another div. It should be possible for users to click on the commercial :).

On my page I have a commercial block. If one clicks the login button the login div will expand and cover part of that commercial (This is intended). This is the part that can't be clicked. How can I prevent this from blocking clicks without moving the commercial in front the expanded login div.

You can see how clicks are blocked by hovering the mouse over the commercial on 
[www.whomakescoffee.com](http://www.whomakescoffee.com)

Comment: Move the ad on the other side? What you say doesn't make a lot of sense, it would mean that when they click on "Hide" for example, they would click on the ad.

Comment: try restyling the login box so that it's more horizontal, less vertical, like your ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around in Chrome, and I think I got it working.

- Take the explicit widths off the login_wrapper, login_leftpanel and
  login_inliner
- Position: relative on body tag
- Position: absolute on login_wrapper
- Remove position: absolute from login_leftpanel
- top: 55px; right: 0; on login_wrapper
- z-index: 25; on login_wrapper

That might do it (although I can't remember if I made more edits...).